# Javascript Platformer- Movement

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I am currently attempting my first game project and have run into an issue. I am not sure why, but my character will not move when a key is pressed. I went back through the tutorial code I am using and my code is verbatim of the tutorial.

It may be an easy fix, but I'm new to web dev and so I am really struggling to debug.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onkeydown="keyDown(event)" onkeyup="keyUp(event)">
<canvas id="graphics" width=600 height=400 
        style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-image:url('images/sky.png');">
</canvas>

<script>
    //VARIABLES
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("graphics");
    var grafx   = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var player  = new Object("images/lookright.png",100,100);
    var isLeft  = false;
    var isRight = false;

    //EVENTS
    function keyDOWN(e) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "97") isLeft = true;
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "100") isRight = true;
    }

    function keyUp(e) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "97") isLeft = false;
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "100") isRight = false;
    }

    //MAINLOOP
    MainLoop();

    function MainLoop() {
        //PRE VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS
        player.X += player.Velocity_X;
        player.Y += player.Velocity_Y;

        //LOGIC
        if (isLeft)  player.Velocity_X = -3;
        if (isRight) player.Velocity_X = 3;
        if (!isLeft && !isRight) player.Velocity_X = 0;

        //POST VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS

        //RENDERING
        grafx.clearRect(0,0,gameCanvas.width,gameCanvas.height);
        grafx.drawImage(player.Sprite,player.X,player.Y);

        setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60);
    }

    function Object(img, x, y) {
        this.Sprite = new Image();
        this.Sprite.src = img;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Previous_X;
        this.Previous_Y;
        this.Velocity_X = 0;
        this.Velocity_Y = 0;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FWIW, there is a StackExchange site specializing in game development: [gamedev.se]. You might find the answers you need here on SO, but you potentially could get better ones on that other site. (But don't post the same question on both sites, as it's not allowed to cross post on StackExchange sites. And I don't want to turn you away from SO, I just want to make you aware that this other site exists :))

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thank you, Alexandre. I will definitely keep that in mind for any future questions I have on Game Dev!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. `keyDOWN` and `keyDown` are not the same.

If something's not working, use the developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome and FF, F12 in IE) and check the Console tab for error messages. In this case I'm pretty sure JS was complaining that the function doesn't exist.

Also: `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == "97"` makes no sense. `e.keyCode` is a number representing the key that was pressed, e.g. 97 for "a". `String.fromCharCode()` expects a number and returns the character corresponding to that number in the character table, so if you call `String.fromCharCode(97)` you get back `"a"`. So you're basically mixing two functioning approaches to create a third one that doesn't work. It should be one of the following:

```
if (e.keyCode == 97) isLeft = true;

if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == 'a') isLeft = true;
```

*However*, you should note that the `keyCode` property is deprecated, and instead it's recommended to use the much friendlier `key` property, which contains the "name" of the key that was pressed:

```
if (e.key == 'a') isLeft = true;
```

Comment: Okay, I have updated the case to 'keyDown', but when I run the game again it still does not work. I appreciate the developer tools tip, it will come in handy, however, the console is no longer showing any error messages.

Comment: Updated answer with further bugs

Comment: Thanks, Mate! The tutorial is older and therefore a little outdated.